# Ret2libc unexpected output

Tags: stack, exploit

I can't understand why when I try to exploit a ret2libc I always get this output

```
sh: 1: 34:ln=01: not found
sh: 1: 36:mh=00:pi=40: not found
sh: 1: 33:so=01: not found
sh: 1: 35:do=01: not found
sh: 1: 35:bd=40: not found
sh: 1: 33: not found
... (continues)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasn't passing an address containing the /bin/sh\0 string but only /bin/sh. I then found that /bin/sh\0 can be easily found in the libc [return to lib_c buffer overflow exercise issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124095/return-to-lib-c-buffer-overflow-exercise-issue)